# Método render me duplica los datos?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Tengo un component que al poner una función dentro del método `componentDidMount` me ejecuta 2 veces lo que tengo en el método render, la 1ra que es la debería ejecutar y vuelve y me ejecuta lo mismo y si pongo otra función dentro del `componentDidMount` se ejectura una más, o sea 3 veces.

Me di cuenta de esto porque estaba validando algunos datos con el `console.log` en el método `render` y mostraba 2 veces la data que pasaba por el `console.log`.

Aquí mi código, hasta ahora estoy empezando en React y he revisado todo y no se por qué me pasa esto.

```
import React from 'react';

class WeatherApp extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
    }
  }

componentDidMount = () => {

    this.geolocation(this.location);

  }

 geolocation = position => {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
  
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position);
  
    } else {
      console.log('No Soporta ubicación')
    }
  
  }

location = async position => {

    const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    await this.getData(latitude, longitude);
  }

 getData = async (lat, lon) => {

    const latitude = lat;
    const longitude = lon;
    const API_URL = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall? 
    lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}`;
    const API_KEY = `c196bcdce7bad59b552b30dbfefd9b2b`;
  
    try {
  
      const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}&appid=${API_KEY}`);
      const data = await response.json();
      this.setState({
        data: data,
        
      });
 
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error.message)
    }
  }

render() {
    console.log(this.state.data);
    const lat = this.state.data.lat
    return(

      <div>{lat}</div>
        

    );

  }
```

El JSX se renderiza una vez pero el `console.log(this.state.date)` se pinta 2 veces en la consola, una con el array vacio del estado y otra con la data de la petición ya en el estado, si pongo un `console.log` con algún string me muestra igualmente 2 veces el string en la consola.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Así es como funciona React JS.

Cuando el componente padre se acopla al árbol DOM, se dispara un primer snapshot de la app en memoria, aquí se propagan objetos como `state` y `props` a los componentes Leaf.

Este primer snapshot, es lo que te muestra la consola en el primer `console.log(this.state.date)`.

No hay datos en el estado, configuración inicial.

Luego, el **Lifecycle Method** `componentDidMount()`, espera a que se acople el componente para ejecutar alguna acción. En este caso, en algun punto de la función que llamas ahí dentro, tienes un API method `setState`, que dispara otro snapshot(conocido como re-render).

Este segundo snapshot, es el segundo `console.log(this.state.date)` que te muestra la consola.

Aqui ya vez los datos en el estado, pues la operación asíncrona ya se completó.

Se puede decir que un **snapshot**, es una **recarga (re-render)** del árbol virtual DOM de React en la memoria del explorador web, es imperceptible a simple vista, pasa muy rápido. Pero se puede observar por medio de capturas en la consola.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda,

Saludos

Comment: Cuando hago un `console.log('string')`  también se imprime 2 veces en la consola, pero en otro proyecto que estoy haciendo con un curso de React no sucede esto, ya hice una prueba en ese proyecto igualmente con un `console.log('string')` y en ese proyecto no se imprime 2 veces, solo una.
Y por esto me esta causando problema en otros componentes, debuggeando llegue hasta ahí, que es donde se re-imprime, pero no se por qué.

Comment: @DanielSantos lo que el compa;ero trata de decir, es que la función `render()` se está llamando 2 veces, la primera vez, cuando se renderiza el componente, y la segunda vez, en el `componentDidMount()` cuando llamas al `getData`. La función `render()` se llama por muchas razones, cuando se utiliza setState, cuando cambien los props o incluso desde el componente forzando el cambio del state con `this.forceUpdate()`