# Theader dinamico con react js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-redux

Tengo una tabla en JSX y quiero cargar una columna de manera dinamica pero no lo la muestra, se queda en blanco.
Primero obtengo datos desde una api y los paso a un array, luego de todo el JSON obtenido paso los campos fecha y los paso a un array, y luego de ese mismo array elimino los repetidos, al parecer se agregan bien pero no muestra el resultado en la tabla.

Ejemplo de mi json

```html
[
  {
    "codigo": 260,
    "nombre": "DANIEL H",
    "campo": 4,
    "cultivo": T1
    "mes": "Octubre",
    "fecha": "2021-10-25"
  },
  {
    "codigo": 123,
    "nombre": "JOSE LUIS",
    "campo": 1,
    "cultivo": T1
    "mes": "Octubre",
    "fecha": "2021-10-25"
  },
  {
    "codigo": 99,
    "nombre": "ANGEL",
    "campo": 1,
    "cultivo": T1
    "mes": "Octubre",
    "fecha": "2021-10-25"
  },
  {
   "codigo": 8,
    "nombre": "VIRIDIANA",
    "campo": 1,
    "cultivo": T1
    "mes": "Octubre",
    "fecha": "2021-10-25"
  },
  {
   "codigo": 260,
    "nombre": "DANIEL H",
    "campo": 4,
    "cultivo": "ZARZAMORA"
    "mes": "Octubre",
    "fecha": "2021-10-25"
  }
]
```

Como ven la fecha se repite y quiero que como tal 2021-10-25 sea el nombre de la columna, ya que eventualmente se añadiran mas fechas.

Aqui mi codigo:

```html
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";
import Contenedor from "../Contenedor.jsx";
import { makeStyles, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  getListProyeccionAction
} from "../../redux/Proyeccion/ProyeccionD";

import '../../css/index.css'

const Proyeccion = () => {
  const styles = useStyles();

  const cookies = new Cookies();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const proyeccion = useSelector((v) => v.proyeccion.arrayProyeccion);

  var fechas = [];
 
  const getData = () => {
    dispatch(getListProyeccionAction(cookies.get("IdUser")));
    //Obtengo un JSON y lleno un array llamado fechas con todos los valores fecha de mi json
    
    for (const x of proyeccion) {
      fechas.push({
        fecha: x.fecha
      });
    }

//luego elimino las fechas duplicadas del mismo array
    var hash = {};
    fechas = fechas.filter(function (current) {
      var exists = !hash[current.id];
      hash[current.id] = true;
      return exists;
    });
    console.log(fechas.length);
  };



  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={styles.root}>
      <Contenedor />
      <div className={styles.content}>
        <div className={styles.toolbar}></div>

        <section className="content">
          <div className="row">
   
                  {proyeccion.length > 0 ? (
                    <table
                      className="table table-hover"
                      style={{ fontSize: 11, textAlign: "center" }}
                    >
                      <thead className="thead-light">
                        <tr>
                          <th colspan={8}></th>
                          <th style={{ backgroundColor: "#B0C4DE" }} colspan={1}>Fechas de actualizaciones</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Codigo</th>
                          <th>Nombre</th>
                          <th>Campo</th>
                          <th>Cultivo</th>
                          <th>Mes</th>
                          <th># Cambios</th>
                          <th>
                            {fechas.length > 0 ?
                              <>
                                {fechas.map((item) => (
                                  <React.Fragment key={item.fecha}>
                                    {item.fecha}
                                  </React.Fragment>
                                ))}
                              </>
                              :
                              null
                            }
                          </th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>
                        {proyeccion.filter(searchData(search)).map((item) => (
                          <React.Fragment key={item.noMes}>
                            <tr>
                              <td>{item.codigo}</td>
                              <td>{item.nombre}</td>
                            // etc..

                            </tr>
                          </React.Fragment>
                        ))}
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  ) : (
                    <>
                      <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                        No hay datos
                      </div>
                    </>
                  )}
                </div>
              </div>
            </>
          )}


        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Proyeccion;
```

Comment: Hola. Para pintar en pantalla el "ReactFragment", debes establecerlo en un return, de tal froma {fechas.map((item, id) => {return ( <ReactFragment key={id}> {item.fecha} </ReactFragment> )})}. Espero que te funcione. Si tienes preguntas al respecto, no dudes en plantearlas.

Comment: @JoshuaRivera gracias por el aporte, pero tampoco me funciona

Comment: @g.4 gracias pero su comentario no tiene que ver con mi pregunta, creo

Comment: @g.4 es correcto necesito que 2021-10-25 sea el nombre de mi columna, eventualmente se añadirán mas fechas y quiero que esos valores de la fecha sean los nombres de las columnas

Comment: Bien, quita el `null` del operador ternario y pon un `<p>test</p>`, para confirmar que llegan datos en `fechas.map`, si despues de recargar sale **test**, entonces hay algún problema con `fechas.map`

Comment: @g.4 ya lo he modificado como dices y tampoco aparece <p>test</p>

Comment: ¿Y los demas `th` aparecen bien en la pantalla? x ejemplo th>Codigo</th> etc... o simplemente no carga nada de la tabla

Comment: @g.4 si todos los demas bien, incluso si reviso el array fechas en la consola si contiene la fecha tambien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No parece haber problemas con la tabla `JSX`. Sin embargo, el problema parece estar en la forma en que se quiere usar la variable `fechas`.

Al declarar `fechas` de esta forma:

```
var fechas = [];
```

No se esta siguiendo el [ciclo de vida del componente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/374132/m%C3%A9todo-render-me-duplica-los-datos/374167#374167), pues como tal `fechas` no es una variable de estado en **ReactJS**, por lo tanto **ReactJS** no tiene control sobre su estado al intentar usarla dentro de `JSX` durante el ciclo de vida.

Se puede ver que el valor de `fechas` se ha modificado dentro del scope de la función `getData`; pero cuando `useEffect` devuelve el componente  `Proyección`, `fechas` vuelve a tomar el valor de su declaración original en el componente:

```
var fechas = [];
```

Entonces, en esta pieza de código siempre se tendrá que `fechas.length` es igual a `0`, mostrando `null` de acuerdo al operador ternario:

```
  <th>
    {fechas.length > 0 ?
      <>
        {fechas.map((item) => (
          <React.Fragment key={item.fecha}>
            {item.fecha}
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
      </>
      :
      null
    }
  </th>
```

---

#### Workaround

Una forma de modificar el código para seguir el ciclo de vida del componente `Proyección`, es usar una variable de estado `local` para `fechas`:

```
const [fechas, setFechas] = useState([]);
```

Luego, en `getData` se aplica el `set` del estado `fechas`:

```
  const getData = () => {
    dispatch(getListProyeccionAction(cookies.get("IdUser")));
    //Obtengo un JSON y lleno un array llamado fechas con todos los valores fecha de mi json
    
    let auxFechas = [];
    for (const x of proyeccion) {
      auxFechas.push({
        fecha: x.fecha
      });
     }
    };
    //luego elimino las fechas duplicadas del mismo array
    var hash = {};
    auxFechas = auxFechas.filter(function (current) {
      var exists = !hash[current.id];
      hash[current.id] = true;
      return exists;
    });
    console.log(auxFechas.length);
    //set del estado fechas, react ya tiene control sobre el
    setFechas(auxFechas);
};
```

---

#### Redux Store es el dueño del estado

> eventualmente se añadiran mas fechas.

Una mejora que se podría hacer, es mover el estado `fechas` a `redux store`, pues al usar el patrón `redux`, se supone que el `store` debe ser el dueño de las variables de estado de la app.

Esto implica, declarar su estado inicial en `store`, crear su `dispatch/action` y traerla al scope con `useSelector`.

De esta forma la app ya no tendrá que usar `fechas` como variable de estado `local`, si no como parte del `store` de redux.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.